# Typescript: Mongoose cast to ObjectId failed for value at path “_id”

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

If I deliberately try to fetch a wrong product ID using postman, the application crashes.

## Reason

The error is **NOT** getting catched by my error-handler middleware.

> **Route**

```js
/* returns a single product */
router.get("/:id", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);
  if (!product) {
    throw new NotFoundError();
  }
  res.send(product);
});
```

> **Not Found Error** (custom)

```js
import { CustomError } from "./custom-error";

export class NotFoundError extends CustomError {
  statusCode = 404;
  constructor() {
    super("Page not found");
    console.log("Not found error");    // <=== Not being consoled out
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, NotFoundError.prototype);
  }
  serialize() {
    return [{ message: "Page not found" }];
  }
}
```

> **Error handler**:

```js
export const errorHandler = (
  err: Error,
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  if (err instanceof CustomError) {
    console.log("Error while processing request");   // <=== Not being consoled out  
    return res.status(err.statusCode).send({ errors: err.serialize() });
  }
  // and if not
  console.log(err);
  res.status(400).send({
    errors: [{ message: "Something went wrong" }],
  });
};
```

I have no clue why the error is not being caught by the **middleware** in the **app.ts file**:

```js
// routes
app.use("/api/product", productFetchRouter);
// error handler
app.use(errorHandler);
```

[Repo](https://github.com/karankumarshreds/ReactReduxAdvanced/blob/master/server/src/app.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your middleware before your routes:

```html
// error handler
app.use(errorHandler);

// routes
app.use("/api/product", productFetchRouter);
app.use(userFetchRouter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get("/:id", async (req: Request, res: Response, next: Next) => {
try{
const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);
  if (!product) {
    throw new NotFoundError();
  }
  res.send(product);

}catch(e){
   next(e);
 }
});

router.use(errorHandler);
```

**Note**: I am not so good with Typescript but that how i do it normally catch the error and then pass it to the errorHandler Middleware by using `next()`